# Packaging Cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova

Using all the relevant links I was able to make Cordova plugin. Now, I've to package this, and provide it another mobile app, which should be able to invoke the plugin.

Can anyone please give me pointers as to what all should be included in the invoker app and  the plugin. (like how should be the plugin packaged.. jar? if yes what all should be available in the jar, and what in invoker apps.

Thanks,
Jeangrey

Answer (score 0):

try to place jar it in the your working Directory and refer your project as a Library...